# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown not working in Laravel - Vue spa

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4, popper.js

Spa.blade.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <title>SPA</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i%7COpen+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- Custom stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('frontend/style.css') }}">

    <!-- include the site responsive stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('frontend/css/responsive.css') }}">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no warnings or errors in the console. It's particularly not working inside the Vue `<div id="app"></div>` element.

As the CDN links not loaded by the Laravel mix. Is this an issue with Laravel webpack.mix.js?

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Are you missing the css sheet? <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice the bootstrap.js which loads popper and jquery by default, hence no need to import these CDN links again.

```
/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

app.js is enough, which loads all the necessary dependencies.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Have alook at it . it is working. please check all the CDN you are using or something is missing.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <title>SPA</title>

    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works if we remove app.js (Vue Instance) but the issue is, it's not working when importing Vue Instance.